# Draw Polygon in Googlemap based marker time

Tags: c#, javascript, google-maps, maps, gpolygon

I want to draw a polygon by connecting markers in googlemap.Time is associated with each marker.So i want connect each points based on the time.How can i do this.Currently code is impleneted like this.Where i need to change.

```
       var marker = new Array();
       var points = new Array();
     for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++)
          {
               var tempar=value[i].split(',');
               var center = new GLatLng(tempar[0], tempar[1]);
               var mar = new GMarker(center, icon);
               var imgpth=tempar[3]; 
               var tme=tempar[2];
               marker.push(mar);   
               marker[i].time = tempar[2];
               points.push(marker[i].getLatLng());
               drawMarker(mar,imgpth,tme);                   
        }
          for(i=;i<marker.length;i++)
         {
            map.addOverlay(marker[i]);
          }
           var polyline = new GPolygon(points, "#f33f00", 2, 1, "#ff0000", 0.2);
           map.addOverlay(polyline);
```

Comment: Have you tried sorting markers by time?

Comment: That's actually the easiest one.

Comment: How can we easily sort points array,which contain marker objects.(Each marker objects contain time property.i want to sort based on this time)

Comment: @WojtekT..thanks for point out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to sort `marker` array by time. Assuming that the `time` property has some sensible values (not strings):

```
marker.sort(function(a,b){return a.time-b.time});
```

If the `time` is a string then:

```
marker.sort(function(a,b) {
 var date1 = new Date(a.time);
 var date2 = new Date(b.time);
 return date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();

});
```

Comment: time property is just a string.how can i able to sort this time string

Comment: after sorting again we need to push it in "Points" array...is it correct?

Comment: one more thing date time string doesnot contain Date value.String will be like this..."19:23:58"

Comment: I can't fix all your problems. I gave you an example, you can figure it out.

Comment: function SortByName(a, b){
   return timeToSeconds(a.time) - timeToSeconds(b.time);
}    
   function timeToSeconds(time) {
    time = time.split(/:/);
    return time[0] * 3600 + time[1] * 60 + time[2];
}  //sorting will be like this..